# Angular 6 on page refresh, in URL symbols "?" become "%3F", and "=" become "%3D"

Tags: angular, url, routes, angular6, query-string

I have URL path `example.net/page-name?search=123`

after page refresh in browser it become like: `example.net/page-name%3Fsearch%3D123`

and redirects from current component to `NotFoundComponent`

Routing module:

```
{path: 'page-name', component: ComponentName},
{path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent}
```

How to preserve symbols "?" and "=" after page refresh, and stay on current component?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably let Angular construct the URL for you by only setting params:

```
return this.http.get(this.myUrl, { params: new HttpParams().set('search','123') })
```

Comment: I should be able to copy this URL, paste it into the browser's address bar and get the correct result. But with this problem it's impossible.

Comment: It will construct the URL with "?" and "="